# Manipulate Iframe element inputs on react

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have an application and I want to have some iframes and try to access to certain fields of that fields and set them some values. Is there a way to do it ? It's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use element `contentWindow` property

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
//x = window.frames[0];

x.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
// this would turn the 1st iframe in document blue.
```

The `contentWindow` property returns the `Window` object of an `HTMLIFrameElement`. You can use this `Window` object to access the iframe's document and its internal DOM. This attribute is read-only, but its properties can be manipulated like the global Window object.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

Comment: But you can manipulate inputs and set their value ?